# Use nearest neighbors to predict text classification with fasttext

Tags: deep-learning, text-classification, fasttext

I may misunderstood how fasttext/deep-learning work for classification, I would like to take in consideration nearest neighbors to predict labels. The aim of my work is to predict label with synonyms.

I train a big dataset with fasttext:

```
fasttext supervised -input data/spam_status.txt -output models/sem -lr 1.0 -wordNgrams 1 -epoch 25
```

Where spam_status.txt use a regexp to labelize message containing the word "skype":

```
__label__skype i dont have skype __NUMBER__ sorry
__label__skype skype
__label__skype si ta un skype si
__label__skype i will give u my skype
__label__skype pv ici no skype
__label__skype skype
```

And plenty of other messages, with other labels, or "ok" if nothing is found.

Nearest neighbors of "skype" are (with `fasttext nn models/sem.bin`):

- email
- viber
- emaill
- skp

This is excellent, fasttext give me good similar words. But if I ask a prediction:

```
fasttext predict-prob ./models/sem.bin -                                                                                          
donne moi ton skype
__label__skype 1.00001
donne moi ton viber
__label__ok 1.00001
donne moi ton emaill
__label__ok 1.00001
```

Why NN is not taken in consideration here?

Answer (score 1):

Because you trained the model with examples where ONLY messages with the word "skype" have the label Skype. Therefore messages with words like "email" and "Viber" are labelled "ok."

Your first pass taught you that you should re-label. Using a regex to label data is always going to cause problems like this. You can now at least re-label any of the messages with "email" or "Viber" as "__label__skype" so it will learn that pattern. However, it will probably not get you anything better than just using a regex as a classifier, because the model will learn the pattern going in: if it has one of the words from this short list, label it "Skype" otherwise label it "ok".

Your get better results by sounding a few hours manually labelling data instead of using a regex.

Comment: So, NN is never taken in account for prediction?

Comment: I don't know what features it looks at, but when there's such an easy pattern, it makes sense that it would only look at that